# R - Match rows in tables by multiple column values

Tags: r

I have two tables in R, 1 and 2 each with several columns. I want to match the rows in table 2 to table 1 based on the values in columns a and b (V1/V2) in table 1 and c and d in table two (V3/V4). The problem is that multiple rows in table 1 correspond to a row in table 2. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Table 1

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11

1   0   200 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   +

2  200  400 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   2   +

3  400  600 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   3   +

4  600  800 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   4   +

5  800 1000 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   5   +

6 1000 1200 chr1  0  0  0  0  0  0   6   +
```

Table 2

```
  V1     V2     V3 V4

221259 chr1 778400 779400 E7

221265 chr1 826600 827600 E7

221300 chr1 924000 925800 E7

221313 chr1 938000 938200 E6

221315 chr1 938400 938800 E6

221323 chr1 941000 942800 E7
```

Comment: check out `?merge`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to share also you attempt to solve the problem with a small snippets of code. Please read carefully SO guidelines about how to ask good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask